# Conditional compilation symbols not being defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio, conditional-compilation, compiler-errors

I am having trouble getting Visual Studio to behave as I would expect it. I created 2 configuration profiles. One has the symbol FOO defined and the other has the symbol BAR defined. And I have this code:

```
static class MyClass{
#if FOO
  public static string const MyData="foo defined";
#endif
#if BAR /*yes, I know #elif would work here too.. just trying to be simple*/
  public static string const MyData="bar defined";
#endif
}
```

and then later in another file I have

```
 if(MyClass.MyData=="foo defined").....
```

Well, in my application, I get an error that MyClass.MyData is not defined.

Also, if I have it on the FOO profile and type in something like `#error test` after the `#if FOO` then it will have a build error, but if I remove that it will build just fine and when I go to run it I'll get a compilation error that MyClass does not contain a definition for MyData. Also, this is an ASP.Net Web Application.

Can someone help me figure out how to use conditional compilation? It acts as if Visual Studio compiles it properly with the compilation symbols, but whenever the ASP.Net webserver executes it, it recompiles it without any symbols... But that just doesn't make any sense why it would do that..

Edit:
It doesn't matter if I use the FOO or BAR profile, neither of them seem to define the MyData symbol as they should.

EDIT2:

Ok, this is important for reproducing!!!
Create a new `App_Code` folder in your solution and then add a .cs file there and then add MyClass to it. This will reproduce the bug working in a blank project. I've actually simplified it down to just

```
#if !(FOO || BAR)
  #error neither foo or bar defined
#endif
```

It seems like Visual Studio does not set conditional compile symbols for regular .cs files inside of App_Code

Comment: I completely changed my answer... Check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since ASP.NET compiles your code outside of your development environment, it uses its own build configuration. You must set the conditional compilation symbol in your web.config, see link here:
[Conditional Compilation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/12/01/conditional-compilation-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx)

Comment: Thats what I did. In the FOO configuration profile, I added the symbol FOO and for the BAR profile I added the symbol BAR

Comment: Weird, the problem must lie somewhere else, are you sure you're actually building using the correct configuration?

Comment: yes.. Like I said, it builds without throwing an error, but then when I run the asp.net website it will load up a Compilation Error page

Comment: Change the Configuration from Debug to Release.  Set the symbol there as well.

Comment: Take a look now - this was your problem probably.

Comment: Possibly.. so you mean if I have my web.config checked into source control, then I must modify my web.config for different configurations(which we test between very often)? That is a crappy solution. Why does it work in my say default.aspx.cs file, but not in app_code/test.cs?

Comment: ok ok... apparently `app_code` is treated as a special folder.... If I rename my app_code folder to `app_code_cs` then it all works as expected... Silly microsoft doesn't tell you about that.. I'm giving you the answer because well.. it's what kicked me and made me figure it out..