# Dynamically Compiled ASP.NET Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to dynamically compile an ASP.NET Web Site (NOT project that has .csproj) depending on the configuration/symbols that I've setup. So under the **configuration manager**, I have the following:

```
DEVELOPMENT
STAGING
PRODUCTION
```

and in **Default.aspx.cs** I have:

```
#if PRODUCTION
      lblMessage.Text = "PRODUCTION";
#elif STAGING
      lblMessage.Text = "STAGING";
#elif DEVELOPMENT      
      lblMessage.Text = "DEVELOPMENT";
#endif
```

And in the **web.config** I have:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>

      <compiler
           language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
           compilerOptions="/d:DEVELOPMENT,STAGING,PRODUCTION"
           type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

    </compilers>

  </system.codedom>
```

HOWEVER, no matter which configuration I select (DEVELOPMENT,STAGING,PRODUCTION), I ALWAYS get PRODUCTION when I view the webpage (after rebuilding). Weird thing is, it always compiles whatever I have last in the "compilerOptions" attribute.

While I can find various questions with solved answers for this question, it doesn't work for me. I've looked/tried at this without success:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/12/01/conditional-compilation-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx

[Conditional compilation symbols not being defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981212/conditional-compilation-symbols-not-being-defined)

http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2008/07/conditional-compilation-in-aspnet.html

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming that you are only using one option at a time in `compilerOptions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be better handled by using [build configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in the project. It's likely that the correct symbols aren't currently defined. By default, there is a debug and release configuration. You need to [create/edit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kwybya3w.aspx) your build configurations to match your symbols. This method will allow you to just select the build configuration you would like to use from the build configuration drop down dialog and build.

In addition, there have been many projects that I painted myself into a corner with all sorts of `#if DEBUG` madness. If you can factor out these conditionals into your configuration files and implement [configuration transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) then you'll make your (or your successor's) life easier in the future.